# How can I mount an Amiga (FFS) formatted hardrive?

Tags: filesystem

I have an old harddrive with some amiga stuff i would like to read. I read on canonicals wiki that Amiga-ffs harddrives should be mountable in Ubuntu - but i had no luck in this. Anyone has any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mount a drive with a special filesystem we may need to tell the mount command what type of filesystem we have. Supported filesystems are:

> adfs,  affs,  autofs,  cifs,  coda,  coherent,  cramfs, debugfs, devpts, efs, ext, ext2, ext3, ext4, hfs, hfsplus, hpfs, iso9660, jfs, minix, msdos, ncpfs, nfs, nfs4, ntfs, proc,  qnx4, ramfs,  reiserfs,  romfs,  squashfs,  smbfs, sysv, tmpfs, ubifs,udf, ufs, umsdos, usbfs, vfat, xenix,  xfs,  xiafs.<sup>[Manpage mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mount.8.html)</sup>

Before we can mount the drive we need to define a mountpoint e.g. like this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/amigadrive
```

After that we can mount an amiga filesystem on drive `/sdx` (replace X by the letter given to your drive, e.g. `/sdc`) to this mountpoint by this command

```
sudo mount -t affs /dev/sdx /mnt/amigadrive
```

A prerequisite is that the drive was recognized by the BIOS (which may be an issue for a very old drive).